# in Java what is the type of file called where I can put all of my constants?

Tags: java, constants

I was wondering where should I put all of my CONSTANTS so they are accessible to all packages and classes in my Java project? And How would I include it into my main class below?

I have a classic ASP background so sorry for any mistakes in code so far below.

The StickyNotes() Class.

```
package base;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StickyNotes extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static String SAVE_CHNGS = "Save changes?";
    private final static String TITLE_AYS = "Are You Sure?";

    private void createStickyNotesGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Sticky Notes");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        // Add Main Menu
        MainMenuBar mainMenu = new MainMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(mainMenu.createMainMenuBar(frame));

        // Add Content Pane // can I pass a layout object?
        frame.setContentPane(ContentPaneCreator.createContentPane());
        // contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add Tool Bar
        ToolBarCreator toolBar = new ToolBarCreator();
        frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar.createToolBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Add Label
        frame.getContentPane().add(
                LabelCreator.createLabel(frame,
                        "use Swing and JavaFX together."), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Display the window.
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        // frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void doExit(JFrame frame) {
        boolean fDirty = true;
        if (fDirty)
            switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(StickyNotes.this, SAVE_CHNGS,
                    TITLE_AYS, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                // if (doSave())
                frame.dispose();
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                frame.dispose();
            }
        else
            frame.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new StickyNotes().createStickyNotesGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How about .properties files at Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have suggested creating a class called `Constants`. I would suggest you *don't* do that. Keep each constant in the most relevant location for it. In the case of the constants you've given, those are localizable text which should probably be in property files to start with.

For "multiple-option" values, you should consider using an enum.

You might *occasionally* create a class to hold a particular set of constants or "effective constants" - like [`Charsets`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) in Guava, for example.

But a single project-wide set of constants? Rarely a good idea. That doesn't mean constants shouldn't be *accessible* project-wide, of course - and simply creating `public static final` fields (or accessor methods) is fine for that, so long as the value is immutable. (If it's mutable, you need to think carefully about threading.)

Comment: Thanks all who helped. @Jon Skeet I have created a config.properties file and have placed it in my base package. I think that should be all I need for now thanks to your post!

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. Really, don't. Put constants in the class where they belong. A constant is very rarely used by more than a few classes. And even if it is, the constant is linked to some specific logic, and should be defined in the class implementing this logic.

For example, suppose you have a default date pattern for parsing dates. The constant for this pattern should be defined in a `DateParser` class, which uses this constant.

Putting all the constants in a single class, anyway, doesn't scale. If your app becomes large, this class will end up containing hundreds of constants with really large names to avoid conflicts, and without any scoping class defining what it's used for.

Answer (score 1):

you create a class and define constants in that class and import it.

Comment: Can this new class be created in the SRC folder above package base; so that it is available to other packages? Or is it better to create the file inside package base; but lose access to the file in the other packages? Thanks.

Comment: Create it as a separate class and import it into the application.You can define any package structure and place the file there.

Answer (score 1):

I create a CONSTANTS.java containing all constants and import it everywhere.There is no hard and fast rule in java as to what the file containing constants should be named.

Comment: Except Java naming conventions, which you violate.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there is no specific classes to store constants.

In some particular context :

- if the constants need to be accessed by a lot of different classes
- and if there is no chance that the number of constants grows during the project,

  it can be a good idea to create a class (named Constant for example) and declare all your constant fields here using `public static final <objectType> <OBJECTNAME>` (OBJECTNAME should be in uppercase).

  Then when you want to use constant add the import in the class with : `import <your_package_name>.<your_constant_class>` and use the constant calling `Constant.fieldname` (if the name of your class is `Constant`)

By the way in your example it seems you want to do that for messages in a Swing application. For this case it's probably not the best solution. Keep constants in the business class where they are used respectively, it will be easier to read and to understand for the other developers. If the project grows (and the number of constants increase) the Constant class will be a real mess.

I only use the Constant class if I really need constants to be used by a lots of different classes, and chance that constants number grows is limited.

Answer (score 1):

The "prehistoric" idiomatic way of making constants was including them into an interface, and then inheriting that interface:

```
// This is archaic - do not do it like this:
interface MyConstants {
    int A = 5;
}

class MyClass implements MyConstants {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Note that A is referenced by itself, not as MyConstants.A
        System.out.println(A);
    }
}
```

Currently, Java provides a better way of achieving the same effect: define your constants in a  single class, and then import that class statically. The class will serve as a way to group relevant constants together:

```
package com.my.test;
public class MyConstants {
    static final int A = 3;
}

package com.my.other;
import static com.my.test.MyConstants;
   class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Note that A is referenced by itself, not as MyConstants.A
        System.out.println(A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Create a **separate class with all the constants** (ie public static final variables).

**2.** Then use the **Name of this class "." (dot) the constant name to access it**.

**Eg:**

**Constant Holding Class**

```
public class MyConstant{


  public static final int MAX = 100;
  public static final int MIN = 10;
  public static final String ID = "5U23";



}
```

**Accessing the Constants from other class.**

```
public class Test{

public void go(){

int m = MyConstant.MAX;

}


}
```

**3.** If you dont want your Class to be touched when doing any changes with the constant in future, try to have a **Property file** which will hold the constant.